# separate categories with comma and srounded by single quote

Tags: filters

hello and sorry for yet another beginner question
i am extracting wordpress categories form the array but i want them to be separated by comma
my code is

```
<?php
$args=array(
'child_of' => 79
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
echo $category->cat_id;
?>
```

this will return some thing like 11223344556677

but i want the result like '11,22,33,44,55,66,77'

thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE faq! This type of question is probably best suited for suited for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), rather than here as the question isn't specifically related to WordPress. You just need to get an array of the IDs (a simple foreach loop could do this - or use the Wordpress' `wp_list_pluck`) and then explode that array:

```
//$categories is the array of category objects
$cat_ids = wp_list_pluck($categories,'term_id');
echo "'".implode(',',$cat_ids)."'";
```

#### Edit

And to incorporate this method into the OP's code example:

```
<?php
$args=array(
'child_of' => 79
);
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    $cat_ids[] = $category->term_id;
}
echo "'".implode(',',$cat_ids)."'";
?>
```

Comment: +1 to this being a **PHP** question, rather than a **WordPress** question.

Comment: thank you both of you, @stephen, i will keep in mind regarding the posting. however Chip solution returned me with '""""' while Stephen was perfect on target

Comment: Glad to have helped. The discrepancy between the solutions was because Chip used `$category->cat_id` rather than `$category->term_id`. I've edited this.